# Bootstrap CSS is overriding the default CSS for Drupal Webforms

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

So as my title suggests I'm currently working on a Drupal webform. The issue is that since we started using bootstrap for page styling, the webform looks like crap.

We figured out that by removing the CSS files given by bootstrap our form shows the way it's supposed to.

Anyone have a clue on how to fix this issue? Perhaps a setting where we can say that bootstrap can't override anything existing or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you declared your CSS file AFTER the Bootstrap CSS? That way yours will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading the Bootstrap files before your main Drupal styles are loaded? If Bootstrap is loaded into the page after your main styles it will override.

Alternatively, you could customize your Bootstrap download to exclude components you would not like included.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Changing the CSS load order will only work if you have written rules that would explicitly override the Bootstrap form CSS. You will have more consistent results by customising your Bootstrap CSS so that it excludes the form-related CSS.